# How can I detect only vertical lines in an image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have this image:

[image: original image]

From that I want to detect only vertical lines, and don't want horizontal lines anyway.

I have written the following code which gives me this result with horizontal lines, too:

[image: second image]

That's my code:

```
import sys
import math
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def main(argv):
    default_file = 'C:/Users/Rizwan/Desktop/amy_images/image2_43WqE0i.png'
    filename = argv[0] if len(argv) > 0 else default_file
    # Loads an image
    src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(filename), cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv.resize(src, (100, 40))
    src = cv.medianBlur(img, 5)
    # Check if image is loaded fine
    if src is None:
        print('Error opening image!')
        print('Usage: hough_lines.py [image_name -- default ' + default_file + '] \n')
        return -1

    dst = cv.Canny(src, 10, 40, None, 3)

    # Copy edges to the images that will display the results in BGR
    cdst = cv.cvtColor(dst, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cdstP = np.copy(cdst)

    lines = cv.HoughLines(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 150, None, 0, 0)

    if lines is not None:
        for i in range(0, len(lines)):
            rho = lines[i][0][0]
            theta = lines[i][0][1]
            a = math.cos(theta)
            b = math.sin(theta)
            x0 = a * rho
            y0 = b * rho
            pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000 * (-b)), int(y0 + 1000 * (a)))
            pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000 * (-b)), int(y0 - 1000 * (a)))
            cv.line(cdst, pt1, pt2, (0, 0, 255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

    linesP = cv.HoughLinesP(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 10)

    if linesP is not None:
        for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
            l = linesP[i][0]
            cv.line(cdstP, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

    cv.imshow("Source", src)
    cv.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Standard Hough Line Transform", cdst)
    cv.imwrite("Source.png", cdst)
    cv.imwrite("Source1.png", src)
    # cv.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Probabilistic Line Transform", cdstP)

    cv.waitKey()
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

And one thing more that this gives me two lines in first-line and two lines in the second line as in original image there are only two thick lines but in the second image it giving me 4 vertical lines.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (intensity) difference between the lighter stripe and the background is just around `10`. The best idea here would be to use [`cv2.adaptiveThreshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3) and morphological opening with some vertical line kernel afterwards, cf. [`cv2.morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f).

Here's some code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io      # Only needed for web grabbing images, use cv2.imread for local images

# Read image from web (is already grayscale)
image = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVrCN.png')

# Apply adaptive threshold
image_thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 51, 0)

# Apply morphological opening with vertical line kernel
kernel = np.ones((image.shape[0], 1), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
image_mop = cv2.morphologyEx(image_thr, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# Canny edge detection
image_canny = cv2.Canny(image_mop, 1, 3)

# Get pixel values from the input image (force RGB/BGR on given input) within stripes
image_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
pixels = image_bgr[image_mop > 0, :]
print(pixels)

# (Visualization) Output
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('image_thr', image_thr)
cv2.imshow('image_mop', image_mop)
cv2.imshow('image_canny', image_canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result of adaptive thresholding:

[image: After thresholding]

After morphological opening:

[image: After opening]

After Canny edge detection:

[image: After Canny]

You can play around with the parameters. Maybe the "shape" of the lines can be improved.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Those cv2 skills :o

Comment: Thanks HansHirse for your reply,  here is the error i get when running your code: --->  image_thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 51, 0)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1645: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'cv::adaptiveThreshold'

Comment: @rizwan Make sure, that `image` is a `uint8` grayscale image, i.e. `image.shape` should be `(height, width)`. Most likely, you tried to pass a color image, i.e. `image.shape` is `(height, width, 3)`. Try `image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` before passing the image to `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`.

Comment: Yes, It solved. And the results are now even better than before. I am really thankful to you @HansHirse :) You really deserve more respect in the field :)

Comment: @HansHirse how can I get the original image's RGB values for the detect lines?

Comment: @rizwan I edited my answer, and added some lines to extract the BGR values from within the stripes.

Comment: @HansHirse I run your code but it gave me one list of 6 lists only. Not all the pixels

Comment: And I also want to get both lines BGR/RGB values separately like: line1_values = [], line2_values = []

Comment: @rizwan Please consider asking a new question, posting the actual code you used, the problems/error occuring and, if necessary for context, link/reference to this question here. All these follow-up questions are out of scope of your original question now.

Comment: Sure @HansHirse